# How to be sure threads are cleaned up

Tags: java, multithreading, future

I have a method producer.postMessage(message) which sends a message to some queue. If for some reason the message could not be sent in a period of time I want this task to be canceled. I came up with the implementation below. My question is if there is an interrupt can I be sure the Future task/ executor service are all shutdown and if not what changes need to be made to make this working without any threads not being terminated.

Thanks a lot

```
public void postMessage(final Object object)
{
    LOG.debug("postMessage object " + object.getClass().getSimpleName());

    Message message = new Message("task", 10, object);

    try
    {
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<?> f = ex.submit(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                producer.postMessage(message);
                LOG.debug("Finished sending message for " + object.getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
        });
        f.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ex.shutdown();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e)
    {
        LOG.error("Could not deliver message to the queue, Check AMQ is running");
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't use `shutdownNow` instead of `shutdown` method? Also `isTerminated` method can be used for checking successful termination of all tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The `shutdown()` method on an Executor will stop it from accepting new tasks, but attempts to complete the running tasks. You should use method `shutdownNow()` to have the Executor request that currently running tasks are stopped.

This may not be necessary however, if you use method `cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)` on the Future object. `f.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` will wait at most 5 seconds for completion of the tasks before returning. Since you submit a `Runnable` rather than a `Callable`, the return will always be null; Runnables can't return a result, while Callables can. What you can do is call `isDone()` on the Future after the get with a 5 second timeout, and if it returns false, it means the tasks has not completed. In that case you can then call `cancel(true)` on the Future to attempt to cancel the task. The true argument indicates that you'll allow the Future to interrupt the thread if it is running. You may want to catch `InterruptedExceptions` in your Runnable and log them. Note however that not every call may respond to interrupt requests (for example, some I/O operations may not, while a lot of Java NIO stuff does).

Calling the shutdown on the executor may no longer be necessary, since it's only used for a single task and should have no other waiting or running tasks, but it's probably still good form.

So your code would become:

```
f.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
if (!f.isDone())
    f.cancel(true);
ex.shutdown();
```